# Flutter Not found: 'package:html/parser.dart

Tags: flutter, html-parsing

i'm have tried using package Parser HTML with Flutter but i'm tried compile, this error is returned:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrapy/scrapy.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as html;
```

```
Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'html' in 'package:html/parser.dart'.
lib/main.dart:3:8: Error: Not found: 'package:html/parser.dart'
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as html;
```

Only html parser is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably did not add package or did not get it.

add in following way.

```
dependencies:
  html: ^0.14.0+3
```

Now run following command in terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Ohhh, i'm forget that the import usages is the pubspec.yaml, thanks!